# Report measurement components for a given Hamiltonian measurement

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I was wondering if there is a possibility to report measurement components when reporting the final expectation values of a qubit operator. For example, if we look at a simple Hydrogen molecule Hamiltonian (parity mapping, minimal basis, $0.7414$ Å) as follows:

$$H_{op} = -1.052\, II + 0.397\, IZ -0.397\, ZI -0.011 \, ZZ + 0.180 \,XX$$

To obtain the ground state energy, we need to calculate the expectation value of the above expression. To my understanding, this can be done using `PauliExpectation()` function from aqua. For this problem, I assume expectation values are computed for each component ($II$, $IZ$, $ZI$, $ZZ$, $XX$) of the above Hamiltonian (multiplied by the pre-factors: $-1.05, 0.39, 0.39, -0.01, 0.18$) and then summed up.

I am wondering if it's possible to report the expectation values for each component, ie just for the $IZ$, $ZI$, $ZZ$ and $XX$ terms, for example. I could very easily then multiply the pre-factors and compute the total expectation value classically.

Comment: This [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/12453/9459) and this [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/13675/9459) might be interesting.